# Scale text to fit in a text box in illustrator using scripts(javascript)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been trying to figure out how to get a font to shrink to fit in to its text box, but it needs to scale down the font size. I want to be able to do it to multiple text boxes at once. I dont have any coding right now. I know a little JavaScripting but not 100% sure how to do if for illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code snippet in [my LinkedIn article: Dealing with Overset Text](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adobe-illustrator-variable-data-dealing-overset-text-vasily-hall/).
The Illustrator scripting API gives one some control over the paragraphs, lines, words, characters and arbitrary text ranges of an Illustrator text frame. One upgrade my script could use though is to incorporate text-on-a-path - maybe someday soon I'll fix it up and update my article.

As for using the snippet, just run it however you choose to run scripts (put into App scripts folder or use File > Scripts > Other Scripts. When you run it, any overset text boxes which are area text will have their font shrunk to no longer be overset. You can use this same snippet with Illustrator variable data to ensure a batch process will not have oversets.

Comment: I have tried using that coding, however, i can not seem to get it to work right. I never actually batch out the files i work with. I have tried playing around with thag code but i just cant seem to make it work

Comment: Aha, I fixed it up so that your document does not have to contain any datasets for it to run. Try it again!

Comment: YOU are the amazer; this is but trivial automated computer code: the true creative powers to inspire the human mind is in the artist, the designer and the crafts-person! But you're totally very welcome.